# Storing a PlaceID for future reference

Tags: here-api

we were wondering if storing or caching is allowed for placeID so we can reference to it for our end users. I’ll explain our project:

We are building a react native app for iOS & Android, that is a communication tool for team sports. We do not plan on using any SDK's, we are planning to use the search and geocode API.

This is the flow: A coach will create an event (such as a game). Inside this game, they have to select an address. We are allowing them to search for addresses via the search data and our own UI. After they have selected the address, they finish creating the event. Once the event has been created, other users such as athletes and parents can view the game which includes the address they have selected, which also uses our own UI.

This is the issue:  Since we are allowing these coaches to create events with addresses, somehow we need to reference the address when an athlete or parents views the event. Hence, why we were asking if it can be cached/stored or something similar. Thanks for any help or guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store and or cache the placeID indefinitely, just no details about the place itself. For example, caching the place address is not allowed.

Comment: can we store the placeID as well? or just cache? Thank you!

Comment: You can store it outside of the cache as well.

Comment: I have a follow up question to this... For the athlete viewing the event with the address (via Lookup by ID). Can we cache for 30 days the address label for the event, for this specific user? Or will we have to call the Lookup by ID every time they visit this page? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah a 30 day cache should be fine as long as it expires after 30 days. I'd say if you are doing client side caching, this should be totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the conversation here but it's my understanding that you can store placeId indefinitely, lat/lon for 30 days and nothing else.
Any other place data you need has to be looked up via the placeId 'once per client app session' using the geocoding service which obviously incurs a cost per lookup. I'm currently investigating this right now as my app has potentially many thousands of documents, each with its own geographical location. Clearly this is going to incur a substantial cost, even if I wish to include the place name when displaying each document.